# To copy values from one form to another form

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have two forms, FORM1 and  FORM2.
I have to display some of the fields of the form1 in the form2 ( with the values selected)when going through the flow.

Can u pls help me to write a plsql procedure for performing the above action.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does FORM1 call FORM2 ?  Or is there a common menu system?

Comment: on submit of form 1 , it navigates to form2

Answer (score 1):

Use globl variables

Global variables are used even when the 2 forms are not related. To define a global variable, you use:

```
copy(my_value, 'global.my_variable_name');
```

on the second form to retrieve the value use:

```
default_value('', 'global.variable_name');
v_variable_value := name_in('global.variable_name');
```

Note: default_value is used to set global.variable_name to a default value in the case is not previously set. Otherwise name_in will raise an exception!
Note2: ALL global variables are varchars.

global variables can be read and writen by any form in the same forms session.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use a PL/SQL procedure to pass the values, first you should save he values in the database. If Form1 calls Form2, you can pass PARAMETERs between forms.